# mySQL task with high cpu usage

Tags: mysql, centos, cpu

Hi i had 2 servers with the same hardware and software configuration, booth servers had the same my.cnf flags.

Centos 7.4
Cpanel
Mysql 5.6
Multi PHP

I execute a task on both servers, and on one of them the task uses 90% cpu but on the other server the same task uses only 0.25%.

Some clue about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They have a different database?

Comment: Is the "Query cache" on (or off) in both cases?  Are you writing to both servers, or only one?

Comment: Please post complete text results of Mysqltuner perl script for each server and we will likely have some clues.